# Gatsby PWA - Missing install icon on desktop and add to home screen on android

Tags: progressive-web-apps, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I am building a gatsby blog site. I have made it PWA. Service worker is installed and its working. The problem I am facing is that the install(plus) icon does not appear on the address bar which usually appears on PWA based websites as well as "add to home screen" icon is also not appearing when I visit the site on android.
So I perform a lighthouse test selecting "Desktop" category, all tests passes except for "Content is sized correctly for the viewport". The icon before this category remains greyout and not turns into green. However when I perform lighthouse test selecting "Mobile" category all tests passes.
Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Are you testing on a device that you have never used before, or are you sure you have TOTALLY cleared out previous tests and the browser cache? The browser will not prompt for install if it thinks it has already done that.

Comment: @Mathias cleared cache but there is no add to home screen popup on android as well as it is not showing install icon on desktop browser address bar even though other pwa sites are showing the icon.

Comment: If you share your URL and/or the code you are using, that would make it easier for others to help. Desktop browser Chrome? If so, you have uninstalled previous installs by going here -->  chrome://apps/

Comment: Also, you are using HTTPS?

Comment: gatsby creates service worker file on the fly when we run build, so there is nothing to do in that file. [This is site URL](https://thegatsbyblog.surge.sh)

Comment: Yes, I am using https

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. I was using

```
icon_options: {
      purpose: "maskable",
    },
```

I found out that purpose should be either "maskable any" or "any". So I used "maskable any" and it worked.